Horizontal invariant vector fields on principal bundles
Let $\pi:P \rightarrow M$ be a principal $G$-bundle. We say that a smooth vector field $X$ on $P$ is $G$-invariant if for any $p \in P$ and $g \in G$, we can write $d \theta_g(X_p) = X_{pg}$, where $\theta_g:P \rightarrow P$ is the diffeomorphism given by $p \mapsto pg$. Let us denote the set of $G$-invariant smooth vector fields on $P$ by $\mathfrak X(P)^G$.
Let $V := \ker(d\pi)$ denote the vertical subbundle. Let $H$ be a $G$-invariant horizontal subbundle of $TP \rightarrow P$: by this I mean that for each $p \in P$, $T_pP$ is a direct sum of $V_p$ and $H_p$, and $d\theta_g(H_p) = H_{pg}$ for all $p \in P$ and $g \in G$. Let $\mathfrak X(P)^G_V$ denote the set of $G$-invariant vector fields $X$ on $P$ such that $X_p \in V_p$ for all $p \in P$. Define $\mathfrak X(P)^G_H$ analogously.
It is straightforward to check that for each $X \in \mathfrak X(P)^G$, there exists a unique smooth vector field $\pi_* X$ on $M$ such that $X$ is $\pi$-related to $\pi_* X$. Moreover, the map $\pi_*:\mathfrak X(P)^G \rightarrow \mathfrak X(M)$ given by $X \mapsto \pi_* X$ is a surjective real Lie algebra homomorphism whose kernel is equal to $\mathfrak X(P)^G_V$. Thus, $\mathfrak X(P)^G_V$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak X(P)^G$.
Question. What about set of horizontal $G$-invariant vector fields? Is $\mathfrak X(P)^G_H$ an ideal of $\mathfrak X(P)^G$? Is $\mathfrak X(P)^G_H$ a subalgebra of $\mathfrak X(P)^G$?
I've tried to come up with counterexamples, but I wasn't able to think of any. My main roadblock is that I don't know of any $G$-invariant horizontal subbundles other than the standard one on the trivial bundle $P = M \times G$, in which case $\mathfrak X(P)^G_H$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak X(P)^G$.

A $G$-invariant horizontal subbundle of $P$ is the same thing as an Ehresmann connection associated with a principal connection on $P$. If $\mathfrak X(P)_H$ denotes the set of all horizontal vector fields, then a basic result about Ehresmann connections is that $\mathfrak X(P)_H$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak X(P)$ if and only if the connection is flat, i.e., has zero curvature. It follows that if the connection is flat, then $\mathfrak X(P)^G_H$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak X(P)^G$ (because it's the intersection of the subalgebras $\mathfrak X(P)_H$ and $\mathfrak X(P)^G$ of $\mathfrak X(P)$). In fact, the converse is also true: if $\mathfrak X(P)^G_H$ is a subalgebra of $\mathfrak X(P)^G$, then the connection is flat. This basically boils down to showing that you can always find a local frame for the horizontal distribution consisting of $G$-invariant horizontal vector fields, and the curvature of a principal connection is a Lie-algebra-valued $2$-form and therefore depends only pointwise on the vector fields it is applied to.
As for whether $\mathfrak X(P)^G_H$ is an ideal, I'm pretty sure that's never the case. I haven't taken the time to work out the general case, but here's a counterexample in the simplest possible case. Let $M=G=\mathbb R$, and let $P$ be the trivial principal $\mathbb R$-bundle $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, with projection $\pi(x,y) = x$, and with horizontal distribution spanned by $\partial/\partial x$. This is a flat connection, so $\mathfrak X(P)^G_H$ is a subalgebra. But it's not an ideal. Consider the vector fields on $P$ given by
$$
X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \qquad
Y = x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
$$
Then both $X$ and $Y$ are $G$-invariant, and $X$ is horizontal. But $[X,Y] = 
\partial/\partial y$, which is not horizontal. With a little more work, you can probably use a similar idea to come up with a counterexample on an
arbitrary principal bundle.
